# Converted dataset fields from type string to schema but now I don't get any results anymore

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset that has a field of type string but as the project has evolved I've needed to turn this into a schema type but when I query the db I don't receive any data. If I however run the same query from a terminal (we are using cloud9) it returns the desired results. What am I doing wrong?

**Dataset before:**

```
rId: { type: String }
```

**Dataset after:**

```
rId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }
```

**Code being executed on call:**

```
var _id = req.body._id;
cars.find({rId: _id}, function (err, results) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({msg:"error occurred"});
    } else {
        res.status(200).json(results);
    }
});
```

I have tried various possibilities (below among them) yet none have worked:

```
var _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(req.body._id);
var _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id);
```

It for some reason will not find the previously created objects that have the **rId** as string type but finds all via the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you cannot find the previously created objects that have the rId as string type but what you can do, and has to be from the terminal, is convert the strings to objects. This worked for me:

```
 db.cars.find().forEach(function(x){ try{ var id = new ObjectId(x.rId);} catch(err){ var id = new ObjectId();} db.cars.save({rId: id}); });
```

This will convert all the string types into Object types. *Need the try catch block or it will error out with; **Error: invalid object id: length**.

Hope this helps others.